# Why does one switch only work when another is on?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

I'm trying to wire up a living room light on a new switch. Prior owners ran wire from panel to outside lights first then back inside to the electrical box that contains the single pole switch. So I have tried to connect the neutral only to the new switch and tap into the hot wire from my outside switch. Doing this makes the new switch only work when my outside lights are on. Do I need a different switch? or is there anything else I can do?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the switch box in question please?

Comment: Currently i have everything out to test what works.  But you can see how i combined the blacks and kept whites separate. The whole issue I'm having is I'm getting my power from my outside lights https://ibb.co/bBp3gFN

Comment: Switch on the right is from the outside lights, Switch on the left only works if the switch on the right is on obviously

Comment: You've drawn the wiring to the switch on the right incorrectly. If it really were wired that way it would trip the circuit breaker as soon as you turned the switch on.

Comment: Sorry here is what i found when i first started by the way this is knob and tube wiring with no ground https://ibb.co/6wSjSrK   https://ibb.co/2sQ9XBH

Comment: It sounds like you have a little bit of experience in electronics or automotive, no idea of the rules for AC mains power, and are just “trying stuff” with the idea of stopping at the first thing that works.  Am I correct?  Well, don’t do that.  Don’t experiment.  Lots of things will work *and then will kill you*.

Comment: Everything about all the drawings is scary and indicates a professional should be called in stat. Please post **photos**. P.S. Switches open and close connections on the hot wires leading to the load... not neutrals (except in special situations).

Comment: Assuming the wires running off the bottom of the image are from the panel, as you've drawn this, the bulb at the top right will _always_ be on and the switch is useless. As drawn, if you connect the red (which I presume is your intended plan), then the bulb on the left will _never_ be on, because there's no complete circuit for it, anywhere. This is why people are asking for pics of the _actual box_, not inaccurate sketches of what you think is happening.

Comment: Sorry my image is not looking the best. I will try and explain. Panel first to Outside lights,Outside lights run back inside to Switch 1 which full works. On that switch i have ONE hot wire i tested with a non contact volt meter second wire is Neutral since i have NO ground with knob and tube. So what i have done is left neutrals alone i added the inside light Neutral to switch 2 which is the living room. Then since my only power is from Switch 1 i jumped off it is all. Now but switches WORK but switch 1 needs ON for Switch 2 to work.

Comment: https://ibb.co/bBp3gFN

Comment: A key piece missing here is an accurate diagram or picture of the wires inside the "outside light box". As drawn, the light would always be on. Which means one of those wires likely *bypasses* the light. For example, hot going to the switch and coming back as **switched hot** to connect to the light.

Comment: I have no idea where them wires are ran outside, the lights by itself are working fine they turn on and off. Should i try and find which light they start from? There is a total of 3 outside that all work as they should

Comment: You have a diagram of "here is how it is wired" with *no verification that it is actually wired that way*. A picture of the wires showing connections/wire nuts/etc. of the first light in the group (i.e., closest to the circuit breaker) would help.

Comment: As requested here is one of the lights outdoors and how the molex from panel is going to knob and tube outside https://ibb.co/Jjj2rD7
https://ibb.co/tm4q2N4
https://ibb.co/bFqXkyn

Comment: @Tom11, please [edit] your pics directly into your original question so people don't have to wonder whether it's safe to click a link to "ibb.co". I'm not doubting you, but who knows where a link shortener points to...

Answer (score 1):

If your original wiring schematic is correct black and white on the switch this is a switch loop, or switch leg!

the power goes to the fixture. Then the hot comes back to the switch on the white it is not a neutral.

at this point do not connect all whites together as someone said. The white “always hot” should be marked as a hot the black complete’s the circuit to the outside light. The switch turns on and off this connection!

New wiring would need to be run the new light. You cannot tap a switch leg to provide power for another device!

Be careful accepting assistance on the internet because there are a lot of people that don’t have a clue I hope you have not damaged things wiring etc.
This is a prime example of internet only electricians in a circle !

Answer (score -1):

Remember that the power comes in through the black wire into the circuit and the neutral returns the power to the source. The switch is just there to interrupt the circuit or complete it. In the illustration, the switch on the left does not complete the circuit; creating a neutral fault.

FIX:

Step1: Looking at the diagram, connect all the white wires together using a wire-nut.

Step 2: Using a wire-nut and two separate black wires, split your (Black) power wire to connect to each switch (on only one black wire, to one screw, per switch). The black wire that comes from each lamp's circuit will have to be connected to either remaining screws (one wire, to one screw, per switch).

Comment: This would be correct if the situation where **Panel -> Switches -> Lights**, but OP has stated it is **Panel -> Light 1 -> Switches -> Light 2**, and in that setup white **is not always neutral**.

Comment: Correct glad you understand what i mean. I tried tracing the lines, they go from panel->outside lights which i have two. I took one down and it has white with white black with black but nothing returns back inside, my guess they did the splitting within the outside siding. My only option i guess i could do smart bulbs leaving the switch on constant. or have a electrician just rewire everything for me.

Comment: Wrong! Switch loops commonly are used and the power or hot comes in on the white the switched hot is on the black per code , the white should reidentified as a hot , the white is used as a hot so it can not be confused as a neutral when it is turned off.